# Why is the squared Brownian motion not a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I'm trying to figure out where my logic is wrong here. Probably I have a dumb mistake somewhere, but I cannot find it on my own.

Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process adapted to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$. We say $X_t$ is a martingale if $\mathbb{E}[X_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = X_s$ for all $s < t$.

I'm looking to prove that the process $X_t = B_t^2$, where $B_t$ is standard Brownian motion, is *not* a martingale. I happen to know that this is indeed the case, because it is well known that $B_t^2 - t$ *is* a martingale, and further by Itô's lemma one can show that the drift term does not vanish, which is a necessary condition for $X_t$ to be a martingale here.

However, I'm able to produce the following (incorrect) proof as follows.
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s] = X_s \iff \mathbb{E}[X_t - X_s | \mathcal{F}_s] = 0 \\
\end{equation}
And
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X_t - X_s | \mathcal{F}_s] &= \mathbb{E}[B_t^2 - B_s^2 | \mathcal{F}_s] \\
& = \mathbb{E}[(B_t - B_s)(B_t+B_s) | \mathcal{F}_s] \\
& = \mathbb{E}[B_t - B_s]\mathbb{E}[B_t + B_s | \mathcal{F}_s] \text{ (by independent increments)} \\
& = 0 \text{ as } B_t - B_s \sim \mathcal{N}(0, t-s)
\end{align}
Hence we get $\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s] = X_s$.

I assume there is some subtlety to using independent increments, but surely $B_t - B_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$? Seems to be part of the definition of Brownian motion or a Wiener process.

Thanks

Comment: Hi: It's the next to last line that's the problem. $E(B^2_{t}) \neq E(B_t)E(B_t)$.

Comment: In the third step, you are essentially assuming that something like $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ holds, which is not true in general. (To see why this discussion is relevant, replace $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ by $\mathbb{E}[\cdot|\mathcal{F}_s]$ and set $X=B_t-B_s$ and $Y=B_t+B_s$, neither of which is $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable.)

Comment: Ah yes right. What a dumb mistake. Independent increments allows us to write it as a plain expectation, but it obviously does not allow me to split it as the terms are by definition not independent. Thanks all.

Comment: Jensen's inequality: the square function is strictly convex.